# working with json result and using strings as keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to work with a json data set that doesnt use numbers as keys but strings

this makes it a bit more complicated to return results.

so if the json structure is something like this

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "data": {
        "tab": {
            "what-you-doing": {
                "tabColWidth": "2",
                "tabColHeight": "2",
                "category": "CategoryA",

            },
            "tab-smaller-78e": {
                "tabColWidth": "1",
                "tabColHeight": "1",
                "category": "CategoryB",

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and i then want to query this

my js to getJson

```
function getJSON (name, path) {


var promise =   $.ajax({
        url: path + name + '.json',
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json'
});

return promise;
}
```

and then working with the data set

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var promise = getJSON('feed', "../data/");

    $.when(promise).then(function(result) {

        $(result.data.tab).each(function(index, element) {

        console.log(element);

        console.log(element['what-you-doing'].category);

        });
    });
```

obviously I dont want to have to specify what-you-doing in the code so how can I get this name within this loop and also look at the results underneath it.

the reason this is no using [] within the json is to make it easier to find this result and not have to do another loop.
    });

Comment: Are you asking how to loop over the keys in an object in javascript? Because the JSON gets converted into a javascript object... You probably just need `for (var key in element) { console.log(key); console.log(element[key]); }`

Comment: yes that is perfect! if you add as an answer i will accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to loop over the keys in an object in javascript? Because the JSON gets converted into a javascript object... You probably just need

```
for (var key in element) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(element[key]);
}
```